# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx

Inside my component i have this function that i call in order to fetch more data if i scroll down the list :

```
  onScroll(event) {
    if (this.shouldGetData(event.srcElement)) {
      this.store.dispatch(new StartAppendRoutesList());
    }
  }
  /* support methods */

  shouldGetData(targetEventElement) {
    return this.scrollAskForData(targetEventElement) && !this.alllistAlreadyFetched;
  }

  scrollAskForData(targetEventElement): boolean {
    const scrollPercentage = ((targetEventElement.clientHeight + targetEventElement.scrollTop) / targetEventElement.scrollHeight) * 100;
    return scrollPercentage > constants.SCROLL_PERCENTAGE_THRESOLD_TO_GET_DATA;
  }
```

Inside my side effects, i have the following :

```
  @Effect()
  appendRoutes = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(RoutesListActionTypes.StartAppendRoutesList),
    switchMap((action: StartAppendRoutesList) => this.service.getRoutes(fromRoot.initialStateRouteList.currentOffset)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(result => of(new EndAppendRoutesList(result))),
        catchError(err => of(new OnError(err.message)))
      ))
  );
```

And my actions are the following which consist of :

```
  StartAppendRoutesList = '[routes] Starting Adding More items to route list',
  EndAppendRoutesList = '[routes] Ending Adding More items to route list',
```

and has the following code :

```
export class EndAppendRoutesList implements Action {
  readonly type = RoutesListActionTypes.EndAppendRoutesList;
  payLoad: RouteList;

  constructor(payLoad: RouteList) {
    this.payLoad = payLoad;
  }
}

export class StartAppendRoutesList implements Action {
  readonly type = RoutesListActionTypes.StartAppendRoutesList;
}
```

And my reducer is like this :

```
case RoutesListActionTypes.StartAppendRoutesList:
  return {
    ...state,
    processingRoute: true,
  };
case RoutesListActionTypes.EndAppendRoutesList:
  const queryResult = action;
  return {
    ...state,
    processingRoute: false,
    currentOffset: state.currentOffset + 5,
    routesList: {
      results: state.routesList.results.concat(queryResult.payLoad.results)
    }
  };
```

Now at first sight, everything works fine when i apply the offset in order to retrieve a certain amount of data or if i choose to retrieve the whole list inside my service :

```
  getRoutes(offset: number): Observable<any> {
    const numberToRetrieve = 5;
    const routes = configUrl.routeBaseUrl["routes"]["results"];
    return of(routes.slice(offset, numberToRetrieve));
  }
```

but once it reaches the end of the list, it start getting me this error : 
[image]

The error shown is at the concat method inside my reducer :

```
routesList: {
  results: state.routesList.results.concat(queryResult.payLoad.results)
}
```

I tried looking for a solution by making a method which will return a `fetched indicator` inside my `createStateSubscriptions` method which get called inside the ngOnInit like this :

```
  alllistAlreadyFetched = false;
  ngOnInit() {
    // state subscriptions
    this.createStateSubscriptions();
    // attaching listeners
    this.createEventScrollSubscription();
    // getting initial data
    this.store.dispatch(new StartLoadRoutesList());
  }

  /* subscriptions and observables creation methods*/
  createStateSubscriptions() {
    // state observable use directly in view through async pipe
    this.listObservable$ = this.store
      .select((state: RoutesListState) => state);

    // all routes fetched indicator
    this.listStateSubscription$ = this.store
      .select(allListItemsAlreadyFetchedValidators)
      .subscribe((allRoutesFetched: boolean) => {
          this.alllistAlreadyFetched = allRoutesFetched;
      });
  }
```

And my `allListItemsAlreadyFetchedValidators selector` is like this :

```
export const allListItemsAlreadyFetchedValidators = createSelector(
  selectRoutesList,
  state => state.routes.currentOffset,
  (currentOffset, TotalRoutes) => currentOffset.currentOffset >= TotalRoutes
);
```

But then i get another error in my component at `.select(allListItemsAlreadyFetchedValidators)` which is the following :

```
ERROR in side-list/side-list.component.ts(43,15): error TS2345: Argument of type 'MemoizedSelector<State, boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type '"routesList" | "processingRoute" | "processingDetail" | "currentOffset" | "selectedRouteItemId" | "selectedRouteItemData" | "errorMessage"'.
  Type 'MemoizedSelector<State, boolean>' is not assignable to type '"errorMessage"'.
```

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="routes-container">
  <div class="wrapper-scroll-y grid-scrollbar">
    <header class="header" role="banner">
      <h1 class="logo">
        <a><span>Routes :</span></a>
        <mat-icon class="icon">add</mat-icon>
      </h1>
      <div class="nav-wrap">
        <nav class="main-nav" role="navigation">
          <ul class="unstyled list-hover-slide" *ngFor="let route of (listObservable$|async).routes.routesList">
            <li (click)= "onListItemSelected($event, route.id)"><a>{{route.name}}</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <app-loader-indicator [show]="(listObservable$|async).processingRoute"></app-loader-indicator>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your state.routesList.results undefined or not an array, you will face to face with that error. To solve it you must check it before concat method. If it is not array or undefined you can directly set results as queryResult.payLoad.results

```
routesList: {
  results: (state.routesList.results && state.routesList.results instanceOf Array)? state.routesList.results.concat(queryResult.payLoad.results) : queryResult.payLoad.results
}
```

Comment: then i get Error Error: Error trying to diff [object Object]. Only arrays and iterables are allowed at DefaultIterableDiffer.push which lead at my component's html at the line where i have  <ul class="unstyled list-hover-slide" *ngFor="let route of (listObservable$|async).routes.routesList">

Comment: it works at the first time to retrieve the first 5 data but once i scroll down i get that error, it has something related to the end of the fetch